# RecyclerView не заполняется с первого раза при открытии

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

Уважаемые люди, не могу понять, почему когда я открываю Фрагмент, вью пустой и в логах вижу что (drlr)wordWorkList.size = 0. Вроде же прописано что нужно добавлять 4 слова.
(сам метод get4words() точно работает, т.к. после поворота экрана он срабатывает. Но почему не сразу при открытии?)
Appreciate any help

In Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DrillerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.cardstack_layout), CardStackListener {

    private val viewModel: DrillerViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var currentWord :Word
    private val drillerAdapter = DrillerAdapter()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.addShownCatsNumbersToCatList()
        viewModel.getLivedataList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            drillerAdapter.submitList(it)
            Log.d(TAG, "drlr wordWorkList.size = " + it.size)
        }
        viewModel.get4words()

        val binding = CardstackLayoutBinding.bind(view)
        val drillerLayoutManager = CardStackLayoutManager(requireContext(), this) 
        binding.apply {
            cardStackView.apply {
                adapter = drillerAdapter
                layoutManager = drillerLayoutManager
                itemAnimator = null 
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCardSwiped(direction: Direction?) {
    if (direction == Direction.Bottom) {
        currentWord.shown = false
        viewModel.update(currentWord)
    }
    viewModel.removeAndAddWord(currentWord)
}

override fun onCardAppeared(view: View?, position: Int) {
    currentWord = drillerAdapter.getWordAt(position)
}

override fun onCardDisappeared(view: View?, position: Int) {
    currentWord = drillerAdapter.getWordAt(position)
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
class DrillerViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val wordDao: WordDao,
) : ViewModel() {
    val drillerCatList = ArrayList<Int>()
    val mList = ArrayList<Word>()
    val mLivedataList = MutableLiveData<List<Word>>()

    fun addShownCatsNumbersToCatList() = viewModelScope.launch {
        wordDao.getShownCategoriesNumbers().collect {
            it.forEach { catNumber ->
                drillerCatList.add(catNumber)
            }
        }
        drillerCatList.forEach {
        }
    }

    fun getLivedataList(): LiveData<List<Word>> {
        return mLivedataList
    }

    fun get4words() = viewModelScope.launch {
        wordDao.get4words(drillerCatList).collect {
            mList.addAll(it)
            mLivedataList.value = mList
        }
    }

    fun removeAndAddWord(word: Word) = viewModelScope.launch {
        mList.remove(word)
        wordDao.get1word(drillerCatList).collect {
            mList.add(it)
            mLivedataList.value = mList
        }
    }

    fun update(word: Word) = viewModelScope.launch {
        wordDao.update(word)
    }
}
```

Я использовал ListAdapter, submitList - это его метод "из коробки", он выглядит так если что:

```
public void submitList(@Nullable List<T> list) {
        mDiffer.submitList(list);
    }
```

Добавил код Адаптера к вопросу:

```
class DrillerAdapter() : ListAdapter<Word, DrillerAdapter.DrillerViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {


    inner class DrillerViewHolder(private val binding: CardstackItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
        binding.root
    ) {

        init {
            binding.apply {
                root.setOnClickListener {
                    val position = adapterPosition
                    if (position != CardStackView.NO_POSITION) {
                        tvNativ.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(word: Word) {
            binding.apply {
                tvForeign.text = word.foreign
                tvNativ.text = word.nativ
                tvNativ.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DrillerViewHolder {
        val binding = CardstackItemBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return DrillerViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DrillerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentItem)
    }

    fun getWordAt(position: Int): Word {
        return getItem(position)
    }

    class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Word>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Word, newItem: Word) =
            oldItem == newItem

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Word, newItem: Word) =
            oldItem.foreign == newItem.foreign && oldItem.nativ == newItem.nativ

    }

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте сначала лэйаутмэнеджер светить и только потом - адаптер

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Comment: Покажите тогда что у вас в `submitList()` методе

Comment: обновил добавил код адаптера

Comment: Кадется понял. У вас addShownCatsNumbersToCatList() не успевает отработать до запроса слов, вот их и ноль штук получается в первый раз. По идее починится, если  get4words() вызывать из конца addShownCatsNumbersToCatList() а не из фрагмента

Comment: хм странно, когда я убираю viewModel.get4words(), и вызываю его внизу тела addShownCatsNumbersToCatList() (вызываю, или прям тело прописываю неважно) - у меня вообще ничего не отображается во вью, а в логах не появляется никакой wordWorkList.size (вообще никакой, даже size = 0 нету). Сколько телефон не переворачивай.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122796/discussion-between-alex-rodionow-and-).

Comment: Меня несколько смущают в вашем коде странные вещи. Какие-то collect, циклы с заполнениями списков, пустые списки... Попробуйте упростить код - возможно, станет проще найти проблему. Например addShownCatsNumbersToCatList должно быть можно переписать как-то так: `viewModelScope.launch { drillerCatList = wordDao.getShownCategoriesNumbers().map { it.catNumber } }`